# NodaTime: From server to client

Tags: c#, javascript, nodatime

I am using NodaTime I am storing time information in the form of Ticks since epoch.

However, I want to pass the number of milliseconds since unix epoch back to the client browser, so I can construct a javascript Date() object. Is there not a way to do this?

If this method is out of the question, does anyone else have a better idea?

p.s. I'm tired of messing with strings because I always have to wonder how they will be interpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 10 000 ticks per millisecond, and NodaTime has a constant for this, viz [`NodaConstants.TicksPerMillisecond`](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/F_NodaTime_NodaConstants_TicksPerMillisecond.htm).

If you are store time in an `Instant` object, you can get the ticks via the [`Instant.Ticks` property](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_Instant_Ticks.htm).

And if necessary, the `ZonedDateTime` can be converted to an Instant via the [`.ToInstant()` method](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_ToInstant.htm)

PS: [v1.2](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2013/11/noda-time-1.2.0.html) claims to have additional Xml and JSON serialization capabilities - possibly this will help you format your js date.